# Gulp inject outputs, but none of the options are working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-inject

I am trying to use 'gulp-inject' plugin to add js files to my index file (Angular App).

The following is a portion of my gulpfile.js:

```
var source = 'src/';
var index = source + 'index.html';
var js = [
    source + '**/*.module.js'
    // More file paths
];

gulp.task('injectJs', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(index)
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(js, {addRootSlash: false, ignorePath: ['src/']})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(source));
});
```

After I run the task, here is the portion in question of resulting index.html file:

```
<!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="/src/js/app.module.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

According to the additional options set in the task, the output src should be '*js/app.module.js*'.

Things I have tried, with no change in result:

- Following some suggestions from the plugin's ['ignorePath' issue on github (click here)](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/issues/28)
- Including only one option (i.e. addRootSlash or ignorePath)
- Using {cwd: 'js/'} as the only option
- Changing 'js' variable to a string (i.e. var js = source + '**/*.module.js')
- Changing ignorePath to a string (i.e. ignorePath: 'src/')

Not sure what is wrong, or what else to try. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You're passing the options to `gulp.src()` instead of `inject()` ...

Comment: Good catch!! Please submit your finding as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var injectSrc = gulp.src([// your custom css path,
                          // your custom js path], {read: false});
var injectOptions = {
    addRootSlash: false, 
    ignorePath: ['src/']
};

return gulp.src(index)
    .pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions)) // here is the inject-gulp
    .pipe(gulp.dest(source));
```